# Arduino timer not counting accuratly

Tags: arduino

I am working on a school project for which I rotate a servo after a cable disconnects and a specific delay is over. This is my current code. We are using an Arduino Uno powered from the USB port

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
int reader=4;
int servo1Pin=8;
Servo servo1;

int value;
int pos=10;
int wacht=5000;
void setup() {
    pinMode(reader, INPUT);
    servo1.attach(servo1Pin);
}

void loop() {
    value = digitalRead(reader);
    servo1.write(pos);
    
  if (value == LOW) {
      delay(wacht);
    pos=180;
  }
    else {
      pos=10;
    }
}
```

`wacht` is the specific delay. When we disconnected pin 4 to break that circuit we don't have a consistent time between the interruption of the power flow and the opening of the servo. It seems to vary from anywhere between 5 to 40 seconds of delay after triggering. Does anyone have any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: `delay()` expands to an inline function.  It is not a timer.

Answer (score 1):

try change

```
    pinMode(reader, INPUT);
```

to

```
    pinMode(reader, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

And  for clarification `delay` don't use timer.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your instructions seem strange.  the usual order is:

- Read
- Decide
- Act

Also, you may want to avoid sending useless instructions to the servo.  For example, when you know the servo is already in the correct position.  You should not rely on eternal code to do the right thing.  In other terms, you have no idea how long servo1.write() takes to execute.

Which would give for your loop()

```
void loop() 
{
    if (digitalRead(reader) == LOW)
    {
        if (pos != 180)
        {
            delay(wacht);    // delay() is only called once, when circuit breaks.
                             // this guarantees immediate response when circuit
                             ∕/ closes again.
            pos = 180;
            servo1.write(pos);
        }
    }
    else if (pos != 10)
    {
        pos = 10;
        servo1.write(pos);
    }
}
```

Also, have a look and implement Peter Plesník's answer.  This will probably solve *some* of your problems.  You input will definitely still have a random lag of up to 5 seconds when closing the circuit, though.